# Own css file is being ignored

Tags: html, css

I would like to integrate two css files in my website but the second css is being ignored. Both files are loaded when calling my site properly.(According to the Development Tool of Chrome)

My Header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/theme.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/main.css"/>
```

some code of this site:

```
<div class="test">Test</div>
```

main.css:

```
.test{
  font-size:300px;
}
```

But this is ignored. Only Styles of theme.css are considered. :(
Can you help?

this is the html file:

```
<html lang="de" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="application-name" content="FWWA" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">

    <title>FWWA</title>


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/theme.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/main.css"/>

  </head>
  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white">
        <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">
                <img src="../Logos/FWWA_Logo.svg" alt="Logo FWWA" class="navbar-brand-img" width="100">
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggler" aria-controls="navbarToggler" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggler">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a href="" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarLeistungen" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id="test">Leistungen</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-xl p-0" aria-labelledby="navbarLeistungen">
                        <div class="row no-gutters">
                            <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
                                <div class="dropdown-img-left" style="background-image: url(../Icons/Code_Icon.svg)">
                                    <h4 class="font-weight-bold text-white mb-0">Want to see an overview?</h4>
                                    <p class="font-size-sm text-white">See all the pages at once.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
                                <div class="dropdown-body">
                                    <div class="row no-gutters">
                                        <div class="col-6">
                                            <h6 class="dropdown-header">Services</h6>
                                            <a href="" class="dropdown-item">Coworking</a>
                                            <a href="" class="dropdown-item">Rental</a>
                                            <a href="" class="dropdown-item mb-5">Job Listing</a>
                                            <h6 class="dropdown-header">Apps</h6>
                                            <a href="" class="dropdown-item">Desktop</a>
                                            <a href="" class="dropdown-item">Mobile</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-6">
                                            <h6 class="dropdown-header">Web</h6>
                                            <a href="" class="dropdown-item">Basic</a>
                                            <a href="" class="dropdown-item">Enterprise</a>
                                            <a href="" class="dropdown-item mb-5">Cloud Hostung</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="" class="nav-link">Preise</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="" class="nav-link">Beispielprojekte</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="" class="nav-link">Über uns</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="" class="nav-link">Kontakt</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="test">Hallo</div>
  <script src="../JavaScript/jQ/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../JavaScript/bs/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the main.css file:

```
:root {
    --main-blue: #0E2DB7;
    --main-green: #09E356;
}

@font-face {
    /*for Header/Navbar only */
    font-family:'Noto';
    src:url('../Fonts/Noto_Sans_HK/NotoSansHK-Black.otf');
    font-weight: bolder;
}

@font-face {
    /*for Header/Navbar only */
    font-family:'Noto';
    src:url('../Fonts/Noto_Sans_HK/NotoSansHK-Bold.otf');
    font-weight: bold;
}

@font-face {
    /*for Header/Navbar only */
    font-family:'Noto';
    src:url('../Fonts/Noto_Sans_HK/NotoSansHK-Light.otf');
    font-weight: lighter;
}

@font-face {
    /*for Header/Navbar only */
    font-family:'Noto';
    src:url('../Fonts/Noto_Sans_HK/NotoSansHK-Medium.otf');
    font-weight: 300;


@font-face {
    /*for Header/Navbar only */
    font-family:'Noto';
    src:url('../Fonts/Noto_Sans_HK/NotoSansHK-Light.otf');
    font-weight: lighter;
}

@font-face {
    /*for Header/Navbar only */
    font-family:'Noto';
    src:url('../Fonts/Noto_Sans_HK/NotoSansHK-Thin.otf');
    font-weight: 100;
}

@font-face {
    font-family:'Nunito';
    src:url('../Fonts/Nunito/Nunito-Black.ttf');
    font-weight: bolder;
}

@font-face {
    font-family:'Nunito';
    src:url('../Fonts/Nunito/Nunito-Bold.ttf');
    font-weight: bold;
}

@font-face {
    font-family:'Nunito';
    src:url('../Fonts/Nunito/Nunito-Light.ttf');
    font-weight: lighter;
}

@font-face {
    font-family:'Nunito';
    src:url('../Fonts/Nunito/Nunito-SemiBold.ttf');
    font-weight: 300;
}

@font-face {
    font-family:'Nunito';
    src:url('../Fonts/Nunito/Nunito-Light.ttf');
    font-weight: lighter;
}

@font-face {
    font-family:'Nunito';
    src:url('../Fonts/Nunito/Nunito-ExtraLight.ttf');
    font-weight: 100;
}

*{
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    margin:0;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.navbar-brand-img{
    max-height: 5rem;
    width:100;
    height: auto;
}
div .test{
    font-size:300px;
}
```

Comment: It should work if u don't misspell the file name or the path is not proper. According to my knowledge and understanding that main.css should have the highest priority

Comment: show us the actual html and also both css files

Comment: Simple issue, you've got a space in your CSS rule `div .test`...should be `div.test`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with your css.

1. missing curly braces on 4th `font-face`
2. It should be `div.test` instead of `div .test`.

Try this and it should fix your issue.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Chrome you can look in your developer tools window. Right click on the `.test` element and click "Inspect" and then look in the "Styles" tab to see what the themes.css rule is doing.

One possibility is that the file is accessing the element more specifically than you are.

For example:

```
div.test {
}
```

has priority over

```
.test {
}
```

and

```
div {
}
```

A more extreme way is to force your CSS rules into effect by setting it as:

```
.test {
  font-size: 300px !important;
}
```

But it's better to work out why the other rule has priority.

Comment: Stop guessing and don't suggest to use `!important` until it is 100% clear that is the last resort. Always await the OP to provide a clear, verifiable sample before answering.

Comment: .test does not occure in theme.css. So should work without specifying, shouldn't?

Comment: @LGSon I've rephrased it. "Stop guessing" - There's nothing wrong with giving suggestions as to why someone is having a problem.

Comment: @RobKwasowski It is for sure if done using an answer, for that, use comments. And with OP's update it is clear your answer is wrong, so again, await until a verifiable sample is available before answering.

Comment: @LGSon "it is clear your answer is wrong" - That's just a needlessly unfair over-generalisation. I gave him some perfectly valid information about CSS rules priority. And seeing as he hasn't provided what's in the theme.css it seems my answer was probably right.

Comment: You are missing my main point. _"my answer was probably right"_ is my main point, simply meaning, do not answer a question until a verifiable sample is available. General description of something as a "guess" (or suggestion) of what it might be is not a good answer. For stuff like that, use a comment, and only when you **know** what it is, post an answer.